# Searching in a tree (tree is not BST)

Tags: c, search, binary-tree

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

It just prints whatever data I pass, if possible please suggest for some optimization.

```
struct node{
int data;
struct node* left;
struct node* right;
};
```

### For new Node Creation

```
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
struct node* node= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
node->data=data;
node->left=NULL;
node->right=NULL;
return node;
}
```

### Returns height of tree

```
int height(struct node* root)  //returns height of a tree
{
int lheight,rheight;
if(root==NULL)return;
else
{
    lheight=height(root->left);
    rheight=height(root->right);
}
if(lheight>rheight)
return lheight+1;
else return rheight+1;
}
```

### Search Function

```
void levelordersearch(struct node* root,int curr,int level,int num)
{
if(root==NULL) return;
if(curr==level)
{
    if(root->data=num)
    printf("Found %d at level %d\n",root->data,level);
    exit(-1);
    else printf("Not Found\n");
 }
 else
 {
    levelordersearch(root->left,curr+1,level,num);
    levelordersearch(root->right,curr+1,level,num);
 }

 }
```

### For each level traversal

```
 void level(struct node* root,int data)
{
int h,i;
h=height(root);
for(i=1;i<=h;i++)
{
    levelordersearch(root,1,i,data);
}
}
```

### Driver program to test the Functionality

```
int main()
{
struct node *root = newNode(1);

root->left = newNode(2);
root->right = newNode(3);
root->left->left = newNode(4);
root->left->right = newNode(5); 
level(root,90);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If tree is not BST, you must traverse all tree linearly (inorder - postorder - preorder) which complexity is O(n)

Comment: Okkk but what if i use the above traversal method BFT...What will be its complexity.Thanks a lot for helping me @burakozgul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in your search funtion, a simple typo

`if(curr==level)
{`
**if(root->data==num)**
    `printf("Found %d at level %d\n",root->data,level);
    exit(-1);
    else printf("Not Found\n");
 }`
 Instead of comparing values you have used an assignment operator which will always print a value.

Comment: Thanks a lot..@nikhil